# Sending notifications via firebase - limits

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does firebase have limits on the list of notifications sent?
Suppose I want to send 5000 notifications.
I need to create 5 packets of 1000 notifications each.
What interval time should I give between notifications?
Is there any limit for sending packages?

Thanks.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

Firebase Cloud Messaging delivers a huge volume of messages to devices, and has no documented limits on its usage. While sending 5,000 messages may be a lot for your app, it will not even be noticed by the FCM infrastructure.

I *do* recommend minimizing the number of API calls and connections though. So if you're sending the same message to all devices, consider [sending them as 10 batches of 500](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-a-batch-of-messages) rather than 5,000 individual calls.